# Run-time error 7: out of memory & speed up code

Tags: performance, vba, excel, runtime-error

I have been working on this problem for some time now and with help from people on here I have managed to come up with two variant to the problem.

The first solution works, but i cannot get the `msgbox` at the end to display the correct information.

The version below works the first time and displays the correct data in the `msgbox` at the end, but if I try and run the code again, it crashes excel, and give me a run-time error 7: out of memory. It breaks at: `wsNew.Name = strWS`, it looks like it is always trying to create the sheets even though they already exists.

I think it might have something to do with `On Error Resume Next, If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then`.

Is it possible to speed this code up in anyway? currently it is looking through 42 rows in the Global sheet but there may be instance where it is in the hundreds, while it is running at a reasonable speed at the moment, as soon as i introduce more rows in the global sheet it will begin to slow down.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim j As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range, FirstAddress As String, sSheetsWithData As String
Dim sSheetsWithoutData As String, lSheetRowsCopied As Long, lAllRowsCopied As Long, bFound As Boolean, sOutput As String

  If Range("L9") = "" Then: MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  Dim lastG As Long: lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).row
  Dim cVat As Boolean: cVat = InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE")

  If sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Cells(35 - cVat * 5, 12) >= 1 Then: MsgBox "It appears you have already split the jobs, this operation can only be performed once.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .CutCopyMode = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

For j = 0 To UserForm2.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
        bFound = False
        currval = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 0) ' value to match
       With sheets("Global")
            Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Range("Q:Q").Find(currval, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not rngCPY Is Nothing Then
            bFound = True
                lSheetRowsCopied = 0
                FirstAddress = rngCPY.Address
                Do
                    lSheetRowsCopied = lSheetRowsCopied + 1
                    strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
                    On Error Resume Next
                    If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then
                    With ThisWorkbook
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    Dim nStr As String: With sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9"): nStr = Right(.value, Len(.value) - Len(Left(.value, InStr(.value, "- ")))): End With
                    Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
                    Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row
                    Dim strRng As String: strRng = Array("A18:A34", "A23:A39")(-1 * cVat)
                    Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).row
                    Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Template")
                    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
                    With sheets("Payment Form")
                      For Each cell In .Range(strRng)
                        If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                          If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                            cell.Offset.value = strWS & " - " & nStr & ": " & CCName
                          Else
                            cell.Offset.value = strWS & " -" & nStr & ": " & CCName
                          End If
                          Exit For
                        End If
                      Next cell
                    End With
                    With wsNew
                      wsTemplate.Visible = True
                      wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
                      wsTemplate.Visible = False
  CODE BREAKS HERE -> wsNew.Name = strWS
                      wsNew.Range("D4").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).value
                      wsNew.Range("D6").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("L11").value
                      wsNew.Range("D8").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value
                      wsNew.Range("D10").value = sheets("Payment Form").Range("C11").value
                    End With
                    With ThisWorkbook.sheets("Payment Form")
                      .Activate
                      .Range("J" & lastRow2 + 1).value = 0
                      .Range("L" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 + 1 & "-J" & lastRow2 + 1 & ""
                      .Range("N" & lastRow2 + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!L20"
                      .Range("U" & lastRow + 1).value = strWS & ": "
                      .Range("V" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I21"
                      .Range("W" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I23"
                      .Range("X" & lastRow + 1).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!K21"
                    End With
                    End With
                    End If
                    With Worksheets(strWS)
                        rngCPY.EntireRow.Copy
                        .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
                    End With
                    Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Range("Q:Q").FindNext(rngCPY)
                Loop Until rngCPY Is Nothing Or rngCPY.Address = FirstAddress
            Else
                bFound = False
            End If
            If bFound Then
                sSheetsWithData = sSheetsWithData & "    " & strWS & " (" & lSheetRowsCopied & ")" & vbLf
                lAllRowsCopied = lAllRowsCopied + lSheetRowsCopied
            End If
        End With
Next j

    If sSheetsWithData <> vbNullString Then
        sOutput = "# of rows copied to sheets:" & vbLf & vbLf & sSheetsWithData & vbLf & _
            "Total rows copied = " & lAllRowsCopied & vbLf & vbLf
    End If

    If sOutput <> vbNullString Then MsgBox sOutput, , "Copy Report"

    Set rngCPY = Nothing

  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: .CutCopyMode = True: End With

End Sub
```

Changes to DirkReichel Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range
  Dim noFind As Variant: noFind = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List '<~~~ get missed items
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: .CutCopyMode = False: End With
  If Range("L9") = "" Then: MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  Dim lastG As Long: lastG = sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row
  Dim cVat As Boolean: cVat = InStr(1, sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE")

  If sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Cells(35 - cVat * 5, 12) >= 1 Then: MsgBox "It appears you have already split the jobs, this operation can only be performed once.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  '~~~ acivate next line to sort (will speed up a lot)
  'Sheets("Global").Range("A3:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row).Sort cells(3,17), 1

  For j = 0 To UserForm2.ComboBox2.ListCount - 1
    noFind(j, 4) = 0
    For i = 3 To lastG
      If noFind(j, 0) = sheets("Global").Cells(i, 17) Then
        k = i
        strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then
          With ThisWorkbook
            On Error GoTo 0
            Dim nStr As String: With sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9"): nStr = Right(.value, Len(.value) - Len(Left(.value, InStr(.value, "- ")))): End With
            Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
            Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row + 1
            Dim strRng As String: strRng = Array("A18:A34", "A23:A39")(-1 * cVat)
            Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).row + 1
         -> Dim wsTemplate As Worksheet: Set wsTemplate = ThisWorkbook.sheets("Template")
         -> Dim wsNew As Worksheet
            With sheets("Payment Form")
              For Each cell In .Range(strRng)
                If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                  If sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").value = "Network" Then
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " - " & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  Else
                    cell.Offset.value = strWS & " -" & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  End If
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next cell
            End With
         -> wsTemplate.Visible = True
         -> wsTemplate.Copy before:=sheets("Details"): Set wsNew = ActiveSheet
         -> wsTemplate.Visible = False
            With wsNew
              .Visible = -1
              .Name = strWS
              .Cells(4, 4).value = sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).value
              .Cells(6, 4).value = sheets("Payment Form").Cells(12, 12).value
              .Cells(8, 4).value = sheets("Payment Form").Cells(9, 3).value
              .Cells(10, 4).value = sheets("Payment Form").Cells(11, 3).value
            End With
            With .sheets("Payment Form")
              .Activate
              .Cells(lastRow2, 10).value = 0
              .Cells(lastRow2, 12).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 & "-J" & lastRow2 & ""
              .Cells(lastRow2, 14).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!L20"
              .Cells(lastRow, 21).value = strWS & ": "
              .Cells(lastRow, 22).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I21"
              .Cells(lastRow, 23).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I23"
              .Cells(lastRow, 24).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!K21"
            End With
          End With
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        While sheets("Global").Cells(k + 1, 17).value = noFind(j, 0) And k < lastG
          k = k + 1
        Wend
        Set rngCPY = sheets("Global").Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & k).EntireRow
        With Worksheets(strWS)
          rngCPY.Copy
          .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End With
        noFind(j, 4) = noFind(j, 4) + k - i + 1
        i = k
      End If
    Next i
  Next j
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: .CutCopyMode = True: End With
  'noFind(x, y) > x = item / y: 0 = name / y: 4 = counter
  noFind(0, 0) = noFind(0, 0) & " " & noFind(0, 4) & " times copied)"
  For i = 1 To UBound(noFind)
    noFind(0, 0) = noFind(0, 0) & vbLf & noFind(i, 0) & " " & noFind(i, 4) & " times copied)"
  Next
  MsgBox noFind(0, 0)
End Sub
```

What i want it to display:
Along with the total number of rows search in Global, i.e if there were 43 rows in global. Then siplay the value of the row that wasn't copied (if applicable) for instance if there was a BRERROR in column Q of the Global sheet the message box would also say: Errors found: &vblf cell.value (1)

[image]

Comment: `Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0` means that the sheet doesn't have a name, so it won't happen...

Comment: No, that works as wanted... If the worksheet doesn't exist it will act like it is true... its the easiest way to check if a sheet exist... He only need to move the `With wsNew` AFTER the `Set wsNew = ActiveSheet` thats all...

Comment: And also check if `Len (strWS) > 0`...

Comment: @DirkReichel. I have moved the `with wsNew` after `Set wsNew = ActiveSheet` but i still get the same run-time error 7.

Comment: @DirkReichel I don't know if it's the *easiest* way for worksheets. A simple `Evaluate("ISREF('" & strWS & "'!A1)")` call will return True if the worksheet exists, and doesn't require error handling.

Comment: @Rory that returns also an error which is checked by the `ISREF`... also looking at the speed, it will be slower... however, thats not the real problem here... if the error pops up (highlighted in yellow) please put in the "direct window" `?strWS` ant tell what it prints

Comment: oh and @atame just for you to know: `.Find` is a pretty powerfull tool, however, it is also the slowest way to get what you want. better use `Application.Match()` or directly loop the cells... `.Find` takes is about 13-25 times the time than match does...

Comment: @DirkReichel My point is it doesn't require an `On Error` statement.

Comment: @DirkReichel & Rory. Hi guys thanks for the input, i tried to follow as best i could but i am completely lost now, sorry.

Comment: @Rory thats true... the error will be accepted and reset inside the application itself (and also doing some other ****)... for ppl being new to VBA that may be easier...

Comment: when the error pops up, `wsNew.Name = strWS` will be highlighted in yellow... having VBA on hold now, just type `?strWS` in the "direct input" window (the window you get the output for `Debug.Print` and hit return... it will then print whats inside `strWS`... if there is no text that simply means its empty... that could be the reason for the error

Comment: @DirkReichel. It show 2793 in the input window. Thanks

Comment: also there may be errors with your `With`'s... having something like `With sheets("Payment Form")` inside of `With sheets("Global")` isnt a good idea at all... you changed so much since the last time... it looks like i need to rewrite everything again :D

Comment: ok... i'll take the old wookbook and check if the error pops up... may take some time...

Comment: @DirkReichel. I still have your original code, this is one other option i was exploring at the same time. But i couldnt get the msgbox to display the correct information with yours. I have used some of you code within this to try and make it run smoother.

Comment: the question is, do you get the error with my code? and if not, then we can go for your outputwindow this time, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED AGAIN** this is a big workover, you need to copy the whole code!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, strWS As String, rngCPY As Range
  Dim noFind As Variant: noFind = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List
  Dim noFound As Variant: ReDim noFound(1, 0): noFound(0, 0) = ""
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = False: .EnableEvents = False: .CutCopyMode = False: End With
  If Range("L9") = "" Then: MsgBox "You can't Split the Jobs at this stage. " & vbLf & vbLf & "Please create the form for the Sub-Contractor First." & vbLf & vbLf & "Please press Display Utilities to create form.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  Dim lastG As Long: lastG = Sheets("Global").Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row
  Dim cVat As Boolean: cVat = InStr(1, Sheets("Payment Form").Range("A20").Value, "THE VAT SHOWN IS YOUR OUTPUT TAX DUE TO CUSTOMS AND EXCISE")

  If Sheets("PAYMENT FORM").Cells(35 - cVat * 5, 12) >= 1 Then: MsgBox "It appears you have already split the jobs, this operation can only be performed once.", vbExclamation, "Invalid Operation": Exit Sub

  '~~~ acivate next line to sort (will speed up a lot)
  'Sheets("Global").Range("A3:R" & Cells(Rows.Count, 17).End(xlUp).row).Sort cells(3,17), 1

  For i = 3 To lastG
    For j = 0 To UBound(noFind)
      If Not IsNumeric(noFind(j, 4)) Then noFind(j, 4) = 0
      If noFind(j, 0) = Sheets("Global").Cells(i, 17) Then
        k = i
        strWS = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 1)
        On Error Resume Next
        If Len(Worksheets(strWS).Name) = 0 Then
          With ThisWorkbook
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
            Dim nStr As String: With Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9"): nStr = Right(.Value, Len(.Value) - Len(Left(.Value, InStr(.Value, "- ")))): End With
            Dim CCName As Variant: CCName = UserForm2.ComboBox2.List(j, 2)
            Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = Sheets("Payment Form").Range("U36:U53").End(xlDown).row + 1
            Dim strRng As String: strRng = Array("A18:A34", "A23:A39")(-1 * cVat)
            Dim lastRow2 As Long: lastRow2 = Sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).row + 1
            Dim wsNew As Worksheet: .Sheets("Template").Copy , .Sheets(.Sheets.Count): Set wsNew = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count): wsNew.Move .Sheets("Details")
            With Sheets("Payment Form")
              For Each cell In .Range(strRng)
                If Len(cell) = 0 Then
                  If Sheets("Payment Form").Range("C9").Value = "Network" Then
                    cell.Offset.Value = strWS & " - " & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  Else
                    cell.Offset.Value = strWS & " -" & nStr & ": " & CCName
                  End If
                  Exit For
                End If
              Next cell
            End With
            With wsNew
              .Visible = -1
              .Name = strWS
              .Cells(4, 4).Value = Sheets("Payment Form").Range(strRng).End(xlDown).Value
              .Cells(6, 4).Value = Sheets("Payment Form").Cells(12, 12).Value
              .Cells(8, 4).Value = Sheets("Payment Form").Cells(9, 3).Value
              .Cells(10, 4).Value = Sheets("Payment Form").Cells(11, 3).Value
            End With
            With .Sheets("Payment Form")
              .Activate
              .Cells(lastRow2, 10).Value = 0
              .Cells(lastRow2, 12).Formula = "=N" & lastRow2 & "-J" & lastRow2 & ""
              .Cells(lastRow2, 14).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!L20"
              .Cells(lastRow, 21).Value = strWS & ": "
              .Cells(lastRow, 22).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I21"
              .Cells(lastRow, 23).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!I23"
              .Cells(lastRow, 24).Formula = "='" & strWS & "'!K21"
            End With
          End With
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        While Sheets("Global").Cells(k + 1, 17).Value = noFind(j, 0) And k < lastG
          k = k + 1
        Wend
        Set rngCPY = Sheets("Global").Range("Q" & i & ":Q" & k).EntireRow
        With Worksheets(strWS)
          rngCPY.Copy
          .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown
        End With
        noFind(j, 4) = noFind(j, 4) + k - i + 1
        i = k
        Exit For
      End If
    Next j
    With Sheets("Global").Cells(i, 17)
      If j > UBound(noFind) Then
        k = i
        While Sheets("Global").Cells(k + 1, 17).Value = .Value And k < lastG
          k = k + 1
        Wend
        If Len(noFound(0, 0)) = 0 Then
          noFound(0, UBound(noFound, 2)) = .Value
          noFound(1, UBound(noFound, 2)) = k - i + 1
        Else
          For j = 0 To UBound(noFound, 2)
            If noFound(0, j) = .Value Then
              noFound(1, j) = noFound(1, j) + k - i + 1
              Exit For
            End If
          Next
          If j > UBound(noFound, 2) Then
            ReDim Preserve noFound(1, UBound(noFound, 2) + 1)
            noFound(0, UBound(noFound, 2)) = .Value
            noFound(1, UBound(noFound, 2)) = k - i + 1
          End If
        End If
      End If
    End With
  Next i
  noFind(0, 3) = 0
  noFind(0, 5) = ""
  For i = 0 To UBound(noFind)
    If noFind(i, 4) > 0 Then
      noFind(0, 5) = noFind(0, 5) & noFind(i, 1) & " (" & noFind(i, 4) & ")" & vbLf
      noFind(0, 3) = noFind(0, 3) + noFind(i, 4)
    End If
  Next
  If noFind(0, 3) = 0 Then
    strWS = "No matches found!" & vbLf
  Else
 -->strWS = "# of rows copied to sheets:" & vbLf & vbLf & noFind(0, 5) & vbLf & "Total lines copied: " & noFind(0, 3) & " of " & lastG - 2
  End If
  If Len(noFound(0, 0)) Then
    strWS = strWS & vbLf & vbLf & "Missed Lines in Global: " & vbLf & vbLf
    For i = 0 To UBound(noFound, 2)
      strWS = strWS & noFound(0, i) & " (" & noFound(1, i) & ")" & vbLf
    Next i
  End If
  With Application: .ScreenUpdating = True: .EnableEvents = True: End With
  MsgBox strWS
End Sub
```

switched `i` and `j` again (but kept the multi copy/paste) to check for missed lines... this code asumes that there are no doubles in the listbox (if there are, that would double copy/paste and i dont think that is wanted)

however, it now should be as you want it:)

Comment: Your code worked the first time, then when i ran it again, it gave me a run-time error'-2147417848 (80010108)': Automation error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients.?? it breake at '.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Insert shift:=xlDown'  never seen that before in my life

Comment: oh wow... now im confused too... have you changed anything in your "Template" ?

Comment: No i haven't changed anything. i even re-load the code you pasted above into anther button and tried it again. but got the same error.

Comment: then i may need the workbook again... if you want you can send it direcktly to timeshockdr@gmail.com cus it will probably involve buissness secrets or something like that you cant make public... its pretty hard to figure out what is going wrong this time :/

Comment: @atame also your code should not cause an error... there may be some errors in the workbook itself (i had that a while ago)... and it endet up in a copy (each part itself not the file) so it worked again :/

Comment: I think it might have had something to do with the copied file, because i have just made anther copy of the original, and done the same test multiple time, and it works without a hitch.

Comment: I did have to make a couple of adjustments. Show in my OP. I need to change how the new sheet was create from the template, because it was overwriting one of the sheets.

Comment: as said, i had this some time ago... it was a different error. however, i was able to figure out where the real bug was and then simply created a new sheet and via vba i copied every part into it (then deleting the orginal) and it worked again... there may be an error in the file itself excel doesnt notice or something like that... you may need to create a new copy from your orginal and then simply paste the code there (that may resolve it)

Comment: Code is now working perfectly!! Just need to sort out the output window. Thanks

Comment: Now works perfectly!! without my edits. Just the output windowt to tackle now. Thanks

Comment: A msgbox would be best please. i have update the OP with what is displayed from the first lot of code, and hopefully a good explanation of what else i would like to see. Thanks

Comment: Nearly there, it only showed the last sheet rows were copied too. Missed items should should only be shown if there is a value in the Global sheet that it cant match with the combobox so in this instance there would be nothing displayed as i know that all values have matches. and what is this Check for all itens in Global that are not in listbox? because all it displayed were the sheets that rows were copied to?? Thanks

Comment: It now displays all the sheet that have had rows copied to it. I'm not to sure about the missed items and the second msgbox. The missed items is just pulling the last end from the combobox and the second msgbox is not pulling errors it is just showing the sheets that had rows copied to them. Thanks

Comment: I added a value on the Global sheet that wasnt in the combobox and it displayed it in the second msgbox, but also displayed the other sheets as well?? Thanks

Comment: So can it be coded to only show the missed items from the Global sheet? i dont need it to show the missed item from the combobox, and can i get it on only 1 msgbox? but if there is no missed entries, then that did is never shown, only show it if there is a error found on the Global? Thanks

Comment: @atame you only want items marked as "error"  which are in global but not in your listbox?

Comment: yesh that is correct. only errors found in the global sheet to be displayed please. Thanks

Comment: Works great!!! Fantastic work, could you please add 2 more things. 1st Total line search in Global under total line copied. and 2nd, if there is an error on the global sheet can i show how many times the error was found ie. BRERROR (1)? Thanks

Comment: will take some time... and my daughter will be home soon (need to go with her to a doctor)... so im not sure if i can make it today... or at least in less than 6h...

Comment: That fine mate!! Family comes first, when you can get to it i would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: @atame includet the error-count... but i need to go now... total lines searched should be an easy `lastG - 2` if i got that right :) (cus the way it works, many lines are skipped based on their value matching the line over it)

Comment: Thanks the error count worked great! If you could have a look at the global count when you have the time i would appreciate it!! Thanks

Comment: @atame What do you want to count in Global? The number of lines? that would be `lastG - 2`... or just the number of loops in `For i = 3 To lastG`?

Comment: @atame simply change the row i have marked... should at least do what you want (hopefully... isn't easy with just the SO-app)

Comment: This may be a huge ask and your more than welcome to say no. If i send you a copy of the workbook, would you consider looking over all the code I have, and checking for accuracy and stability, and potentially make adjustments if needed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96296/discussion-on-answer-by-dirk-reichel-run-time-error-7-out-of-memory-speed-up).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your request:

While this is exactly that kind of work i really like, there some problems you should consider:

1: There is allways the possibility I'm a bad guy (who is only helping you to trick you at the end) using the data providet to harm you or your company.

2: The data itself may be counted as "business secret" and giving it to someone may get you in real big trouble. (regardeless of #1)

3: Normally people get [paid](http://www.freelancer.com) for doing this kind of work, which can get me into trouble.

4: Even having all the data, doesn't tell me how it needs to be at the end. (You would need to explain EVERY single bit to me)

5: You would need understand what i've done or you were dependent on me.

At least, when optimizing code you should read something like [this](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx) or [this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm).